How do I authorize access to a publish content link for an Azure runbook created in bicep?
I'm using bicep to extract data from an Azure DevOps file:
resource runbook 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks@2022-08-08' = {
  parent: automationAccount
  name: runbookName
  location: location
  properties: {
    runbookType: 'PowerShell'
    logVerbose: true
    logProgress: true
    logActivityTrace: 1
    publishContentLink: {
      uri: runbookContentUrl  // Retrieves the PowerShell script from this url to put into the runbook
      version: '1.0.0.0'
    }
  }
}

I formed a working runbookContentUrl for DevOps using these two links to guide me:
Is it possible to have a link to raw content of file in Azure DevOps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/source-providers/get-file-contents?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0
Currently, I'm unable to authorize access to the content link in the bicep template.
Note: the bicep template isn't broken as it works fine when the link is a github raw link (when no authorization is needed)
The GET call to my runbookContentUrl was successful in Postman with a Build:Read personal access token. However, it fails when I run it in the bicep template. Is there a way to integrate the PAT into the bicep template or is  there another way of authorizing this request in bicep?

seems no better way here,  1) git raw file, 2) azure storage account raw file.   local file and azure devops repo file not works.
